# Бесплатное хранение БД и подключение к ней с внешней программы

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите, где можно бесплатно разместить базу данных, что бы потом к ней можно было подключиться по интернету?
Спасибо.

Comment: На бесплатном хостинге, где никто не даст никакой гарантии о её сохранности.

Answer (score 2):

У [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) сейчас есть предложение о бесплатном предоставлении услуг для БД MS SQL Server. Условия - [AWS free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/)

Answer (score 2):

Heroku и девелоперская квота на примочку [Xeround](https://addons.heroku.com/xeround) (MySQL в облаке). Бесплатно: 10Mb всего, правда.

Answer (score 1):

Если подойдет MongoDB, здесь предоставляют бесплатно 0,5GB

https://mongolab.com/products/pricing/

https://www.mongohq.com/pricing