# Хостинг внешних БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Никак не могу найти ничего подобного. Мне нужен хостинг(или как это называется) баз данных MySql. Сайт лежит на сервере, но база данных в комплект не идет. Я не совсем понимаю как это устроено, но должны же быть подобные сервисы.

Только что нашел такую же [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198708/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) про бесплатные сервисы, но это почти бесполезно и опасно. [Амазон](http://aws.amazon.com/ru/rds/pricing/) слишком дорого и далеко.

Comment: А сами не хотите такой организовать на стороннем VPS? Правда скорость может быть не ахти, что еще усугубиться необходимостью зашифровать канал связи.

Comment: @cheops я в этом настолько ноль что об этом смешно думать. Я умею использовать их в своих целях, но не понимаю как это устроено...

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, у Вас есть виртуальный хостинг. Виртуальный хостинг, как правило, предоставляется каким-либо хостером по определенным тарифам. Каждый тарифный план включает в себя набор тех или иных услуг. В большинстве случаев только самый дешевый тарифный план (или бесплатный хостинг) не включает в себя базу данных. Поэтому меняйте тарифный план на более дорогой. Или, если у Вас бесплатный виртуальный хостинг, возьмите нормальный за небольшие деньги.

*P.S.: возможен еще такой маловероятный вариант, как то, что у Вас виртуальный сервер. На нем по умолчанию идет уже установленным апач и сайт можно прикрутить без проблем. Но вот база mysql не идет по умолчанию. Поэтому ее просто надо установить.*

Comment: Нет. В этом и проблема. Сайт лежит на lxc контейнере, я впервые с таким работаю но меня уверяют что баз данных на нем нет. Я ищу сервис что бы их подключить.

Comment: @Levelleor можете дать ссылку на Ваш тарифный план?

Comment: @Levelleor Если у Вас есть доступ к контейнеру через SSH (пароль и логин учетной записи с root-правами), то, как я написал в постскриптуме - просто установите базу данных.

Comment: @Alex Нету там тарифов :) Это заказчик уже давно дружит с представителем "хостинга", у которого своя машина с lxc контейнером. У меня есть доступ к файлам по FTP, но баз данных, как я уже говорил, в комплект не идет. Заказчик не хочет уходить отсюда ибо деньги уже были уплачены, хотя я предлагал и настаивал на виртуальном хостинге, что делать?

Comment: @Max ZS root прав нету...

Comment: @Levelleor Вы можете сделать как написал Max ZS либо купить VPS и на ней развернуть базу данных. Можем ошибаться, но некоторые хостинг-площадки также позволяют удаленно подключаться к БД.

Comment: @Levelleor Ну есть очень много вариантов: 1) Просить, чтобы установили базу данных; 2) Просить, чтобы дали доступ по SSH и соответствующие права; 3) Снова и снова пытаться объяснить заказчику, что это не комильфо; 4) Послать заказчика на... Можно еще варианты придумывать, но это уже будет похоже на флуд.

Comment: @Max ZS Тобишь вы тоже предлагаете просто взять и перенести все на виртуальный хостинг? В плане тут неплохая скорость загрузки страниц и это меня даже удивило.

Comment: @Alex VPN значит частная сеть, тобишь вы предлагаете мне создать свою машину? Нет... Я не сильно понимаю как это работает и считаю без помощи не стоит браться за это сейчас.

Comment: @Levelleor Не VPN, а VPS. И не создавать, а как и виртуальный хостинг - заказать по какому-нибудь самому низкому тарифному плану.  И в целом, глаза боятся, а руки делают... Да, это займет время. Нужно будет изучить то, с чем не сталкивались - страшную операционную систему Linux или подобную. Работать только через черную-пре-черную консоль, набирая все ручками. Но. Надо же расти над собой и развиваться в профессиональном плане.

Comment: @Levelleor не VPN, а VPS - Virtual Private Server. Если в кратце тоже что и хостинг только лучше. На нем Вы можете развернуть бд и удаленно к ней подключаться. Или можно попробовать купить хостинг, но нужно узнать перед покупкой можно ли к БД подключиться удаленно. В России одни из лучших цена/качество **[здесь](http://www.reg.ru/?rid=44259)**

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил, и подумал что странно что мне тут советуют VPN, который звучит как что-то не то :) Я вас понял, товарищи, будем выбирать виртуальный хостинг.